# Updating react state inside an input

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, react-hooks, state

I'm working on a React Hook form and I'm trying to update a field that comes already with saved data inside the input.

I'm having a syntax doubt because after I refresh the page, the data is still not changed in the input.

What can I do in this case? Thanks.

```
const Form = () => {
 const [value, setValue] = useState('');

 const updateForm = e => {
  setValue(e.target.value);
 }

 return (
   <div onSubmit={updateForm}>
     <Component type="text"/>
     <Button type="submit" onClick={updateForm}></Button>
   </div>
 )}
```

Comment: It's not clear about the actual issue you have

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab here and say `Component` is the input. If that's the case, you have to set a `value` and `onChange` prop on it to track the changes in the parent, `Form`. If `Component` is *your* component, you'll have to expose them via props if you haven't. It'll look something like,

`<Component value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />`

If `Component` has data "inside" it, you have to "lift state up" to the parent via a handler passed in as a prop as I've demonstrated. If `Component` is a third party component, they'll likely have the props as part of the component's API already.

I don't know what you're trying to do with putting an `onSubmit` on the div, but `onSubmit` is used when submitting a `form` to the server via POST.